# How to scale NSTextView to show rich text in actual size?

Tags: cocoa, scaling, nstextview

The rich text in an NSTextView displays on my screen (27" Mac) a lot smaller than the font size would imply, although it prints correctly, and is the correct size if pasted in to another app (e.g. OpenOffice). TextEdit shows the same behaviour.
The following lines in `awakeFromNib` fixes this more or less exactly.

```
 [myTextView scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(96.0/72, 96.0/72)];
 myTextView.layoutManager.usesScreenFonts = NO;
```

So it looks as if the screen is using 96 points per inch. If I don't have the 2nd line, the text is slightly squashed up, and monotext mangled. Obviously I shouldn't hard code the scale factor, but where can I find the factor to put there? From `[NSScreen mainScreen].deviceDescription` ( a dictionary) I get NSDeviceResolution = {72, 72}", so it seems that's not what's being used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is wise, but you can get the "real" DPI from the display mode:

```
CGDirectDisplayID displayID = [window.screen.deviceDescription[@"NSScreenNumber"] unsignedIntValue];
CGSize size = CGDisplayScreenSize(displayID);
CGDisplayModeRef mode = CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode(displayID);
NSSize dpi;
dpi.width = CGDisplayModeGetWidth(mode) * 25.4 / size.width;
dpi.height = CGDisplayModeGetHeight(mode) * 25.4 / size.height;
CGDisplayModeRelease(mode);

[myTextView scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(dpi.width/72, dpi.height/72)];
myTextView.layoutManager.usesScreenFonts = NO;
```

Some display modes are letterboxed. These will presumably never be used as the general mode for the Mac GUI; they'd only be used by full-screen games. However, if you want your app to handle such a mode, it should account for the fact that the mode size does not correspond to the full screen size in one dimension and the DPI calculation above will be off. I don't think there's a direct way to figure that out. You have to examine all available display modes to see if there's one that's the same in relevant properties (size, pixel encoding, etc.) as the current mode but whose IOKit flags indicate that it's stretched (`CGDisplayModeGetIOFlags(mode) & kDisplayModeStretchedFlag != 0`) while the current mode is not. In that case, you probably want to assume the pixels are square and pick the smaller of `dpi.width` and `dpi.height` to use for both.

Comment: So we have to calculate it! (BTW, the dot notation for unsignedIntValue won't compile for me.)

Comment: Fixed the `-unsignedIntValue` thing. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, I'm getting 109 dots per inch calculating this way, and the factor 109/72 is slightly too large. Thanks for pointing the way; I'll start reading up on core graphics.

Comment: Too large compared to what? Since Windows used a hard-coded 96 DPI for a long time (just like OS X uses hard-coded 72), cross-platform apps like OpenOffice may just be using the 96.0/72.0 that you originally used. Doesn't mean they are more "correct".

Comment: Font sizes are defined in points, which I thought were 1/72 inch in anybody's system, that being a printers' measure. From the Cocoa Drawing Guide (p18): "The user coordinate space uses a fixed scale for coordinate values. In this coordinate space, one unit is effectively equal to 1/72 of an inch. Although it seems like this might imply a 72 dots-per-inch (dpi) resolution
for drawing, it is a mistake to assume that. In fact, the user coordinate space has no inherent notion of pixels
or dpi."

Comment: Well, fonts don't always match their font sizes. For example, not all 12-point fonts are the same height. The point size of a font is a rough guide to relative scale. But unless you're holding a ruler up to the screen, you don't know which of my suggested calculation, OpenOffice, or Cocoa's unmodified behavior is correct (if any are). In your question, you asserted that OpenOffice is correct and I was asking how you determined that.

Comment: From Cocoa Text Architecture Guide: "Type systems usually measure font metrics in units called points, which in OS X measure exactly 72 per inch. Adding the distance of the ascent and the descent of a font provides the font’s point size."  I want the text to display at the same size as it prints. As it is, choosing a font size suitable for printing (usually 10 or 12pt) is almost too small to see in an NSTextView. Printing to a pdf and displaying at actual size on screen does show the text at exactly the same size as printed. TextEdit (which uses NSTextView) has the same behaviour.

Comment: Returning to this after 3 years, now with another app writing in Swift. The line `myTextView.scaleUnitSquare(to: NSMakeSize(96.0/72.0, 96.0/72.0))` works, but only if you put it in a `DidLoadNib` method. Putting it in `awakeFromNib` caused the system to spiral out of memory.